# Sending String to C++ from Android app using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to send a dynamic String , obtained from end user in Android App using JNI.
Though after searching on internet for similar examples , it is quite complicated for me like a newbie to work it out.

I am sharing my code, below for each file.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   static {

      System.loadLibrary("native-lib");

   }

   public native int initialize();

   // i want to send params like String from android App in the below method , what is the proper way to do it.
   // public native int sendData(String param1 , String param2);


}
```

**native-lib.cpp**

```
#include "jni.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_newapp_myapp_MainActivity_initialize(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance){

    activity = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);
    return my_initialize(my_jvm, activity);
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include "jni.h"

int my_initialize(_JavaVM*, jobject);

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My question here is , how to send the String parameters within a method to C++ from Android. for example implementing the sendData() method in MainActivity , equivalent code for JNI file and the same for C++ file.

**Note : Code is very huge that is why i have shared snippet. The code is working properly.**

Comment: `javah` or `javac` can generate the C++ declaration for you based on the Java declaration. Just search around - there must be plenty of examples of how to do that.

Comment: the jni code is being generated auto from android studio also,
but i wanted to know what datatypes to use in JNI code and in C++ side code too,

Comment: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/

Comment: I'm not following. If you're already auto-generating the C++ header then you should already have a C++ prototype for `sendData`, so you should know that it will receive two `jstring`s (aside from the `JNIEnv*` and the `jobject`).

Comment: @Oo.oO : Provided link literally solved 70% of my questions .
so if i call a method in JNI code , like 
passParams(c_str); ,, my method signarure in .h file for c++ code will be int passParams(const char *);  right ?

Comment: @Michael : Actually it is only generating the method signature in JNI cpp file and not in my C++ SDK , in which my actual implementation is written.

Comment: Ok, but in "pure" C++ you're free to use any type you want. So that's up to you.

Comment: @Michael : that why i need help here. can u provide the snippet which i have to use.

Comment: You have to follow strict naming convention to get it solved. You can use either javah or javac with location for headers to generate proper method signature.

Comment: @Oo.oO : the signature is being prepared automatically for **JNI** in android studio.
Can u give a snippet of the signature of the method to be used in main.h file.

Comment: If 'the code is working properly' what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your files are:

```
public class AppCompatActivity {

}
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   static {
      System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
   }

   public native int sendData(String param1 , String param2);

}
```

All you have to do follows:

```
> javac -h . MainActivity.java
> cat MainActivity.h
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class MainActivity */

#ifndef _Included_MainActivity
#define _Included_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     MainActivity
 * Method:    sendData
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_MainActivity_sendData
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Wow. that useful. but i need to write the header file for c++ file also. 
do i have to use the same data type as jstring in cpp method signature and include jni.h

Comment: for example . suppose if i write method passData(jstring_var1 , jstring_var2); inside Java_MainActivity_sendData(){}

Comment: You can use the very same header for both, C and C++. Take a look here for sample where I call C++ code: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-045/ - you can find sample code here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo045

Comment: And here, you can find sample where C++ is called from C based JNI wrapper: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo025